# controller undefined error while working with custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run tabs application and is not working. Please find the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKtq6C?p=preview). Can any one help me to make it work?

```
Error: enTabsController is undefined
```

I am using the code from https://github.com/nervgh/angular-tabs with few modifications but some how it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is wrong.

The end of '' is at a wrong place.
Correct this and then put: require: '^enTabs' in your directives enTabPane and enTab.

```
      <en-tabs data-container="myContainName"> 
            <en-tab data-pane="myPaneName1" >Tab #1</en-tab>
            <en-tab data-pane="myPaneName2">Tab #2</en-tab>
            <en-tab data-pane="myPaneName3">Tab #3</en-tab>

            <en-tab-pane data-name="myPaneName1">
...
            </en-tab-pane>
       </en-tabs>
```

See the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/sX3kzw?p=preview

Comment: But I need to have </en-tabs> closing <en-tab> but not <en-tab-pane>. Please see my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rTehl67kY9wOIR0qmyyC?p=preview , when I click Tab #1 I should get  {"index":1,"count":3}, when I click Tab#2 I should get {"index":2,"count":3}, etc and trying to set active class for the currently clicked <en-tab>  directive. I don't expect you make the entire tab application to work or at lease if can help me to fix this that is fine, for sure I can't have </en-tabs>  at the end.